# user interface for multiple selection filter?

Tags: filter, interface

I have a user interface where there is a field with multiple options. There are a great many options so I'm using a type-ahead filter to assist discovery and selection.

Is there any another good way to do it or is mine the good way?

The first filter works on letter base and then second works on the checked selection - so there is TWO layer of filtration here.

[image: http://postimage.org/image/8jeajk1tv/]

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [token-field design pattern](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/the-multi-select-solution) for displaying and selecting the multiple options. This has the advantage of letting the user see all the items they have already selected while they select more, not just the options that match the current filter.

Some token-field implementations also implement the type-ahead filter design pattern you have.

[Chosen by HarvestHQ](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is pretty nifty for this.

> [image: Multiple select using Chosen - items selected from drop-down menu are accumulated as tokens inside the field]

Comment: This very site is using this pattern for adding tags.